# Get Time in firebase database using angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using Angularfire2 and I'm tesing to build a chat app that pushes messages in the database. I want to get the time when the data is pushed. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Firebase uses a constant value which is replaced with a numeric timestamp when it is written to the database. This removes the need to track and synchronize the time across clients.

[`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.ServerValue)

You can then read the value of the reference that was just written to see the exact time.

```
var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref('sessions');
var mySessionRef = sessionsRef.push();
mySessionRef.update({ startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
mySessionRef.once('value').then(function(dataSnapshot) {
  var time = dataSnapshot.child('startedAt'); // the time when the data was written
});
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this one, but how do you implement this in Angular 2 Typescript? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a value that you can include in any written data. I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38665208/edit) to describe exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: if you're using AngularFire2 you are using a wrapper around firebase and I don't see any access to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP either

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database['ServerValue']['TIMESTAMP']
```